# DC/OS: remove history for a specific service ID

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

How do i remove history for a specific service id in DC/OS 1.11.0?

We have service Ides that have failed when we tested docker containers and we want to remove the history for this service id. Before we start a new container on that id, so we easily can see if this fails again or if it was the old docker container that failed or the new one that failed.

But when we delete the service and start a new one on the same ID it remembers the old history of the task.

**[History of a service id just an example]**

[image]

Or are we force to change the service incrementally in order to have a clean service history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. The setting is the same for all services.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans for chancing this in the future? or is there a reason for this behavior i am not considering?

Comment: I don't know if there are plans to change that. I think it's based on https://github.com/dcos/dcos/blob/master/gen/dcos-config.yaml#L466 (Maximum number of completed tasks per framework to store in memory. (default: 1000))